# Changing Text in Visio Org Chart Shape Changes Multiple Shapes' Text

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have inherited an organizational chart that was created in Visio 2003.  I am updating it with Visio 2007.  When changing the text in one shape, such as a person's title, multiple shapes nearby change their text to the same.

For example, if I change Bob's title from Programmer to Programmer/DBA then Wendy's text will change to "Bob - Programmer/DBA".

Some changes update three or four other boxes.  Some changes will only update one box. My thought is the originator copied or duplicated the one box to create multiple boxes and it created some type of link between them.

How do I remove this link?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up opening in 2003, saving as a 2002 drawing and was then able to edit in 2007.  However, the drawing will ultimately wind up in a PowerPoint 2007.  When the 2002 saved drawing was imported into PowerPoint it displayed the same behavior.  So, perhaps it's not a Visio 2003/2007 issue but rather a Visio/PowerPoint problem.