# Link two or more text boxes in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio

I am working on creating a template in Visio 2007 (Professional).

Each page should reflect a document number and a revision number (two text boxes).  I would like to make the template such that entering or changing text in one of these boxes on one page will automatically update the equivalent text boxes on all other pages.

Is there an easy way to link two (or more) text boxes to show the same data (mirror each other)?

I've looked into creating a ShapeData set and then using the ShapeData field in place of each box, but this will require training others to access and adjust the ShapeData field.

In short - I want the issue that was attempting to be solved in [Changing Text in Visio Org Chart Shape Changes Multiple Shapes' Text](https://superuser.com/questions/42405/changing-text-in-visio-org-chart-shape-changes-multiple-shapes-text) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Background page and place the text box with the universal information there. [This KB from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305325) explains how to create a background page, and how to apply it to each of your foreground pages. This solution has the benefit of being very simple for your users.

If that's not what your looking for, perhaps you could elaborate?

-- jm

Comment: Works wonderfully, and in conjunction with [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255102) you can do more interesting things.  And with Professional there are [title blocks](https://office.microsoft.com/en-in/visio-help/adding-title-blocks-to-visio-diagrams-HA001182247.aspx).  Marking as accepted answer since it got me on the right path to finding all the information I needed.